Intersection of zero schemes defined via sections of vector bundles
Let $X$ be a scheme, and let $\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F}$ be vector bundles over $X$.
Consider non-zero global sections $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{E})$ and $t \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})$. These define maps of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ modules $\mathcal{O}_{X} \xrightarrow{s} \mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X} \xrightarrow{t} \mathcal{F}$.
We dualise to obtain $\mathcal{E}^{\vee} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{\vee} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}$. The images of these maps define quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals on $X$, hence closed subschemes. Call these closed subschemes $Y$ and $Z$ respectively.
I would like to understand the (scheme-theoretic) intersection $Y\cap Z$. Specifically, I feel as if it should be possible to understand this intersection using the maps $\mathcal{O}_{X} \xrightarrow{s} \mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X} \xrightarrow{t} \mathcal{F}$, but I haven't been able to figure out the details.
I am in a situation where I would like to prove that the intersection  $Y\cap Z$ is $\textbf{empty}$, so maybe there is something one can say about this situation? The only thing I can think off is to analyse the composition $\mathcal{E}^{\vee} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$, but I am not sure if this buys you anything? Maybe if this composition is zero, the intersection is empty?
I have tried to look at Fulton's Intersection Theory, but I cannot find anything that helps.
Any help/reference suggestions would be much appreciated!

You can try to study the sum $\mathcal E^\vee \oplus \mathcal F^\vee \to \mathcal O_X$. This defines the ideal sheaf of $Y \cap Z$.

@red_trumpet Ahh, nice. I suppose this defines the ideal sheaf of the intersection because the ideal sheaf is the sum of the ideal sheaves of the closed subschemes. Thanks!
